# What is the most efficient way to strip all spaces and quotes from a string with python?

Tags: python, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

I have a string I want to put between 2 double quotes on output `"{{ var }}"`, so I want to make sure all single/double quotes are removed from the ends of the user-supplied string. What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Inputs / desired outputs:

```
   """""""""" string here '''''''''''''''         => 'string here'
       string'''''''""""""''''''"""""  => 'string'
```

Comment: Would like to see a duplicate. Everything found does not specify multiple instances of characters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) with a string containing the characters you wish to strip from the ends:

```
s = s.strip(' "\'\t\r\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from string import whitespace
new_string = string.strip(whitespace + '"\'')
```

Using the [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.strip) method, with the [`whitespace`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.whitespace) constant to start off your list of characters to remove.