# Removing non-token punctation marks from a string

Tags: python, regex, punctuation

I am trying to strip certain punctuation from my test in python. Essentially, I made a token counter and am trying to remove all excess punctuation (i.e. quotation marks, etc.) that surround a word without removing any relevant token information (i.e. apostrophe's).

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098561/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-strip-all-spaces-and-quotes-from-a-string-with?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570182/how-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-text-file?lq=1) for inspiration. However, the proposed solutions do not necessarily address my problem.

For instance, I have cases of strings such as: `''couldn't`

where I want to remove the `''` but not the `'` between ***n*** and ***t***

So far, I have tried using `re`

such as:

```
excludeLine = line.strip(' "\'\t\r\n')
```

and

```
excludeLine = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',line)
```

and

```
excludeLine = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', line)
```

which not only strip all of the punctuation, resulting in `couldnt` but it also strips all token-relevant punctation such as, the `-`
in words such as `state-of-the-art` leaving me with `stateoftheart`.

Does any one have a solution that removes only those external, syntax/grammar-necessary punctation, such as quotation marks, single quotes (but preserving the apostrophe, hyphen, etc.), exclamation points, periods... etc.

**EDIT**
This is the `re` that I am using to extract the individual token strings.

```
counter.update(x for x in split("[^a-zA-Z']+", line) if x)
```

Could it be that I need to refine it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
excludeLine = re.sub(r'(?!\w.\w)(?:.|^)\K[^\w\s]', '', line)
```

(if your lib supports `\K` )

Answer (score -1):

```
re.sub(u"\u005C[nrt]", r"", YOUR_STRING)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still giving me a problem. It is not removing all of the single quotes. After implementing your proposal, I still have issues such as: `1 'obliterating'`
`1 'ny`
`1 'nut`
`1 'nudge`
`1 'novel'dscribed`
`1 'noughtie'`.... etc.